Missing Flow Reports Analytics package?
I'm beginner with SF flows, and I'd like to be able to view some information on current/past executions. After exploring a bit, I've found this page:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_monitor_on_canvas_insights.htm&type=5
Which tells me I need to install a package called "Flow Reports Analytics".
My problem is I can't find this package anywhere...
What am I missing ? is that old stuff ?
Thanks

"For Data Cloud-triggered, segment-triggered, and form-triggered flows, element run data shows directly on the flow canvas. [...] Available in: Enterprise and Unlimited Editions with Marketing Cloud Advanced Edition". If you don't have all of that or Event Monitoring, out of the box you're stuck with some basic monitoring

right, we don't have marketing cloud so that'll explain it, thanks
